# How to save AWS API Python code to a CSV with Nonetype

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, date, datetime

I have a code that successfully pulls out data between 2 specific times but it gives me an error when I try to save it as a csv.

Here is the code:

```
import argparse
import boto3
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json



parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--days', type=int, default=30)
args = parser.parse_args()


session = boto3.Session(profile_name='UMW')
cd = session.client('ce', 'us-west-1')


results = []

token = None
while True:
    if token:
        kwargs = {'NextPageToken': token}
    else:
        kwargs = {}
    data = cd.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={'Start': '2020-03-11', 'End':  
'2020-06-10'}, Granularity='DAILY', Metrics=['AmortizedCost'],
                                GroupBy=[{'Type': 'DIMENSION', 'Key': 
'LINKED_ACCOUNT'}]} ,{'Dimensions': {'Key': 'LINKED_ACCOUNT','Values': 
['12394850028']}}]}, **kwargs)
    for info in data['ResultsByTime']:
        for group in info['Groups']:
            print(group['Keys'][0], info['TimePeriod']['Start'], 
group['Metrics']['AmortizedCost']['Amount'])#, group['Keys'][1])
    token = data.get('NextPageToken')
    if not token:
        break


with open('test.csv', 'w',) as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([results])
```

I'm trying to save the results to a CSV but this gives me a blank CSV. it runs but comes out with no results and prints the results on the command line.

Comment: use `input` https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/python-user-input or add 2 more arguments : start,end dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```py
def ask_date():
    year = int(input('Input year'))
    month = int(input('Input month'))
    day = int(input('Input day'))
    date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    return date
```

If you use a specific date format (dd-mm-yyyy) that you know your users will aways use correctly, you can ask the date in this format, then parse it

```py
def ask_date():
    res = input()
    day, month, year = res.split('-')
    date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    return date
```

Comment: how do I get this to be apart of "TimePeriod" on my script?

Comment: You don't even need to convert to a date object, just use
"cd.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={'Start':input(), 'End':  
input()}[...]"
if you trust your user enough to correctly input data

Comment: I believe the AWS API doesn't allow inputs and requires the date in the code. Thank you for your answer though

Comment: Using the code I provided in the above command, input() functions will be evaluated and the AWS API will only see a normal string, exactly the same as you're doing now

Comment: This worked thank you. How would I save as csv? I keep getting a TypeError: iterable expected: not nonetype

Comment: You should print your `data` variable, it will get you more information

Comment: it prints on the command line but won't allow me to write the list to a csv